# How can I see the log of the changeset where it is in the tree?

Tags: git

I want to see the git log of a changeset at the time it was created. Say I have

```
$ git log --oneline
123456 most recent stuff
243456 slightly older
153456 a while ago
123354 jeez I forgot about this
888234 is this even the same project?
123999 initial commit
```

And I want to remember what the 'jeez i forgot about this' commit did. I believe I could do

```
$ git diff 888234..123354
```

to see the change. Is that really the only way it do it? It seems clunky because it forces me to look up two SHAs rather than only the one I'm interested in.

Is there a way to do this succinctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git show 123354` is that what you are looking for?